# django reports invalid form with request method POST

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I render the html when login url is hit and then invoke another url to handle submitted form.
Following is the method that processes the form -

```
def process_loginform(request):
    print(request.method)
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        print("Valid form")
    else:
        print("Invalid form")
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/login/welcome/")
```

The Login form html -

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
Hello
<form action="/login/process_loginform/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input id="username-val" type="text" name="username-name" />
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input id="password-val" type="password" name="password-name" />
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

forms.py -

```
from django import forms
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label="username", max_length=64)
    password = forms.CharField(label="username", max_length=64)
```

Console output -

```
(ubuntu-7Wf190Ea) ubuntu@ip-172-31-4-242:~/ka$ ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:1890
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
February 14, 2024 - 10:28:18
Django version 4.2.10, using settings 'ibs.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:1890/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

[14/Feb/2024 10:28:23] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 729
request: <WSGIRequest: POST '/login/process_loginform/'>
POST
**Invalid form**
```

I'm following this documentation - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/forms/

Why is the form invalid ?

I tried to google the error, no luck.
I was expecting to understand why is my login handler reporting an invalid form.

Thanks

Comment: I also tried the following password field in forms.py, no luck - 
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the names of your fields are wrong.

Your `LoginForm` has 2 fields named `username` and `password`. Just use those **names**.

The Login form html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    Hello
    <form action="/login/process_loginform/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="username">Username
        <input id="id_username" type="text" name="username" />
        <label for="password">Password
        <input id="id_password" type="password" name="password" />
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

More info:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#building-a-form
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually